# DidComponentUpdate Infinite Loop React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

Why DidComponentUpdate is on Infinite Loop?

I trying to get some data from an Api When user changeText on Input

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState){
    if (prevState.userinput !== this.state.userinput){

fetch('https://'+this.region+'.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/'+this.state.userinput+'?api_key='+this.apikey+'RGAPI-484c0156-6203-4611-b281-c3933b6ac175')
.then(respostauser => respostauser.json())
.then(json => this.setState({user : json}));
fetch('https://'+this.region+'.api.riotgames.com/lol/champion-mastery/v4/champion-masteries/by-summoner/'+this.state.user.accountId+'?api_key='+this.api_key)
.then(respostamastery => respostamastery.json())
.then(json => this.setState({usermastery : json}));
this.x ++;}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), setting state inside the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method **must** be done using some conditional check(s), else you'd encounter an infinite loop.

This is because by default, an update to state causes the `componentDidUpdate` method to be invoked. In your snippet above, this lifecycle method contains logic that would unconditionally update state (`this.setState`), hence the infinite loop.

Comment: I'm using

if (prevState.userinput !== this.state.userinput)

has be said in docs,its not enough?